# Multi column indexes uuid and created_at is not used

Tags: postgresql

With a multi column index, it seems like the indexes are not take into consideration, when i do a WHERE or a ORDER BY.
On an example table for 100 users

```
create table users (
  id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() not null constraint users_pkey primary key,
  created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
create index users_id_created_at_idx on users (id desc, created_at desc);
```

This is the test:

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
SELECT id, created_at
FROM users
ORDER BY id DESC, created_at DESC;

Sort  (cost=10.63..10.68 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=1.821..2.676 rows=100 loops=1)
  Output: id, created_at"
  Sort Key: users.id DESC, users.created_at DESC"
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
  Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Seq Scan on public.users  (cost=0.00..10.20 rows=20 width=24) (actual time=0.018..0.861 rows=100 loops=1)
        Output: id, created_at"
        Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 0.059 ms
Execution Time: 3.476 ms

EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
SELECT id, created_at
FROM users
WHERE (id, created_at) <= ('fddb1fa4-d68a-460f-a19f-d722fdf60971', '2022-01-21 17:41:05.936547')
ORDER BY id DESC, created_at DESC;

Sort  (cost=7.78..8.03 rows=99 width=24) (actual time=1.883..2.810 rows=99 loops=1)
  Output: id, created_at"
  Sort Key: users.id DESC, users.created_at DESC"
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
  Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Seq Scan on public.users  (cost=0.00..4.50 rows=99 width=24) (actual time=0.009..0.953 rows=99 loops=1)
        Output: id, created_at"
        Filter: (ROW(users.id, users.created_at) <= ROW('fddb1fa4-d68a-460f-a19f-d722fdf60971'::uuid, '2022-01-21 17:41:05.936547'::timestamp without time zone))"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
        Buffers: shared hit=3
Planning Time: 0.114 ms
Execution Time: 3.783 ms
```

I don't get why it is not using the index. Is it because of the date ? The index follow another format ? Is it because of the uuid ? Or the multi column index ?

Comment: For a table with 100 rows, it doesn't much matter what you use.

Comment: I think this already has answers in your previous question, [Does truncate a timestamp break the indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70802558/does-truncate-a-timestamp-break-the-indexes)

Comment: @jjanes So postgres decide by himself the different scan depending on the size of the table ?

Comment: @Bergi In my previous one it was more about the operation done on a indexed column, there I don't get why it is not using the indexes while I have the "correct" (I think) query

Answer (score 0):

Your first query has no `WHERE` clause so it requires to scan the full table `users` and a sequential scan will be more efficient than an index scan in this case.

The second query selects 99 rows out from 100 rows, only one is filtered, so in this case again, the planner considers the sequential scan as more efficient than the index scan.

Comment: When are the cases where postgres use the index scan instead of the seq scan ? There is a limit like 10000 row ?

Comment: Impossible to know in advance the strategy selected by the planner, this is the beauty of the rdbms :-) Then you can force sometimes the strategy by restructuring your query (for instance when joining several tables). The best is to trust the planner, and in case of performance issue, to analyse the specific situation with EXPLAIN ANALYSE.